# Setting up launch icon, but shows only android default

Tags: android

I Have setted on my AndroidManifest on tag Application the attribute android:icon, but it's not working. I have added an image with name icon.png on folder drawable-hdpi,drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, but it insists to show default android icon.

What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks

My AndroidManifest is just like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="..." android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="My App Name"
    android:theme="@style/notitle"
    android:persistent="true" >
```

I Have also added an external libray, and it's AndroidManifest is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="....lib" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: have you tried uninstall of app from the device, and clean rebuild?

Comment: Yes, uninstall, change icon name. It does not change for nothing

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the android:icon attribute in the activity tag which has launcher intent filter

Answer (score 0):

Check out if you have a folder in your res only named as drawable. Their might be an icon with the name icon.png different then the icons u placed in drawable-hdpi,drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi folders.